# feature hashing in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using FeatureHasher in scikit-learn.

Can anyone explain why I end up with 4 non zero data in the sparse matrix instead of 2 after the following:

```
>>> f = FeatureHasher(input_type='string')
>>> g = f.transform(('as','bs'))
<2x1048576 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> g.data
array([-1.,  1., -1., -1.])
>>> g.nonzero()
(array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32), array([341263, 354738,  98813, 341263], dtype=int32))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears is expecting a sequence of sequences. The outer sequence being for the observations, and the inner being features. With your input, the inner sequence are the characters of the string.

Observation 0: 'a' -> 354738, 's' -> 341263

Observation 1: 'b' -> 98813,  's' -> 341263

Try this:

```
g = f.transform([['as'],['bs']])
```

For output:

```
>>> g.nonzero()
(array([0, 1], dtype=int32), array([494108, 335425], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: thanks. Was this clear in the documentation? I do not think so but want to know.

Comment: Not sure about the docs. I feels more like a convention of sklearn. Most transform  functions except a two dimensional grid observations on the row axis, and features on the column axis. If you only give it a one dimension sequence, it will try and find the other dimension by treating the string as it's sequence of features.

Comment: Yes, this is in the `transform` docstring: "`raw_X` : iterable over iterable over raw features, length = `n_samples`".